# How to use bitmap of captured image for scanning QR Code?

Tags: android, bitmap, zxing

I am working in QR Codes project. I have used ZXING library for generating QR codes. I want to scan QR Code in my app. But for that i am using my own custom camera. In my camera i have captured image and created the bitmap of captured image. Is it possible to use that bitmap for scanning QR Codes by calling the decode functions of ZXING library and passing that bitmap or byte[] in it? I will be thankful to you for helping me. Here is my implementation,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO OnCreate Method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);
    cameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    activity = this;
    filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (checkCameraHardware(this)) {

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, cameraId, mCamera);

        try {
            // Get Camera Parameters
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            // Set the Focus Mode
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera Available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera Not Available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO OnPause Method
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();
}

// TODO Detecting Camera Hardware
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // This device has camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // No Camera on this Device
        return false;
    }
}

// TODO Accessing Camera
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;

    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Takes the picture and write to file

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("PICFILE",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            updateGallery();

            // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
            // data.length);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    TestActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Image", data);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("IOEXCEPTION", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use decode method .Check the below code for implementation.

```
String detectBarCode(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), intArray);
    Reader reader = new QRCodeReader();
    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source)));
        return result.getText();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```